# Read response before send it

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

I am sending a plain text file to the user through a servlet.

I am using flatworm framework to build the flat file. I receive the file in the browser but is empty. So i want start the debugging analysing the outputstream before being sent.

How i can read the response before i send it in the servlet? I think is the same thing that asking how can i transform an `OutputStream` to an `InputStream`.

I already saw solutions that always involve `ByteArrayOutputStream` , and as you know when i call in the servlet `response.getOutputStream()` it returns me an `OutputStream` and not a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: By the way, this question could be considered analogous to "how do I read a letter before I send it (through the post)?".  If you're writing it yourself, just read it; if your secretary is writing it for you, ask him/her for a copy (the exact best way to do this depends on the secretary).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion somewhere, though I'm not sure exactly where.

What can you do with an [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)?  Why, you can write to it, and that's about it.  That means that if you're *given* (or look up) an output stream, it's up to you to supply the data - which means you already have it.

Perhaps on the other hand, you're not directly calling `write` on the OutputStream yourself, but passing this stream into the flatworm library (which will in turn write output to it).  In that case, there's your debugging "hook" right there - flatworm will write out the file to any output stream you send it.  So in this case, instead of passing in the servlet's stream, you pass in a stream that you've created yourself.

That might be a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which (after the flatworm method has returned) you can inspect to get the bytes written.  At this point you could manually write them through to the response's output stream.  Or maybe you need to do something slightly trickier and create your own stream wrapper which writes straight through to the underlying response stream but logs on the way - and pass this into flatworm.

The bottom line however is that if you're interacting with an output stream, then "your" code already has the data somewhere locally and it's just a matter of capturing/accessing that.

Comment: First of all thanks to by the reply.
But how can i inspect the ByteArrayOutputStream ?Do I have to transform the ByteArrayOutputStream to an InputStream ?How can i do it ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just one more thing , i can not use the toByteArray method because i am using the JVM 1.2

Comment: Apparently there is still a `toByteArray` method in 1.2 ([link](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/doc/jdk1.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html))?  AIUI the whole point of a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is to put the output into an array you can get at, so I don't see what the class would do if it didn't have that method.